# How many rectangles can be observed in the grid?

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, permutations, combinations

In a $2 × 4$ rectangle grid shown below, each cell is a rectangle. How many rectangles can be observed in the grid?

[image: rectangular_grid]

---

#### My attempt:

I found a formula somewhere,

Number of rectangles are $= m(m+1)n(n+1)/4 = 2\times4\times3\times5/4 = 30$.

> Can you please explain this?

---

#### Upadte -

The post
[How many rectangles or triangles.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1240264/how-many-rectangles-or-triangles) looks similar, but that has $3 \times 4$ grid and I need more variant explanation.

Comment: This post should be reopened because this post has 12 times more views than linked post.

Comment: See also: [Analysis of how-many-squares and rectangles are are there on a chess board?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/178693)

Comment: @MartinSleziak, why people gave down-votes?

Comment: I asked here to reopen this post as some level of duplication is good: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/29024/234055

Comment: Duplicates aren't automatically deleted, right?

Comment: @AkivaWeinberger, please see- https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/28692/requests-for-reopen-undeletion-votes-volume-07-2018-today/29024#29024

Comment: @MithleshUpadhyay Having this many views and a negative score are, as far as I can tell, a great reason *to delete*.  Getting that much attention and no positive feedback indicates it is not useful.  I'm sure if you twittered one of the better-written duplicates, it would accrue at least as many views and a lot more upvotes (because their content is actually good.) . Anyhow, it doesn't give me any heartburn to have this question *undeleted* but *closed as duplicate* since so many links to more general problems have been provided.

Comment: Ok sir, you [vote for delete](https://math.stackexchange.com/posts/1656686/revisions), but do you know who is [Inventor of the Delete button](https://shazgood.wordpress.com/2007/09/05/history-of-the-inventor-of-the-delete-button/);), that [the guy is in the circle](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/28692/requests-for-reopen-undeletion-votes-volume-07-2018-today/29024#comment122999_29024) :).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To form a rectangle, we must choose two horizontal sides and two vertical sides.  Since there are three horizontal lines, we can choose the horizontal sides in $\binom{3}{2}$ ways.  Since there are five vertical lines, we can choose the vertical sides in $\binom{5}{2}$ ways.  The number of rectangles we can form is 
$$\binom{3}{2}\binom{5}{2}$$

In general, the number of rectangles can be formed in a $m \times n$ rectangular grid with $m + 1$ horizontal lines and $n + 1$ vertical lines is the number of ways we can select two of the $m + 1$ horizontal lines and two of the $n + 1$ vertical lines to be the sides of the rectangle, which is 
$$\binom{m + 1}{2}\binom{n + 1}{2} = \frac{(m + 1)!}{(m - 1)!2!} \cdot \frac{(n + 1)!}{(n - 1)!2!} = \frac{(m + 1)m}{2} \cdot \frac{(n + 1)n}{2}$$

Comment: Should we always assume a square to be a rectangle in such cases, if not mentioned otherwise?

Comment: Yes.  A square is a rectangle in which adjacent sides are congruent.

Comment: @N.F.Taussig, your answer is also going to delete :(

Comment: Duplicates are not automatically deleted.  You could argue that the post should not be deleted since it has a useful answer.